# Run action once per Observable's value emission

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

Suppose we have the following code ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-update-global-state)):

```
  public counter: number = 0; // Some arbitrary global state

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const subj: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

    const obs: Observable<number> = subj.asObservable().pipe(
      tap((): void => {
        ++this.counter;
      }));

    // this.counter increments for each subscription.
    // But supposed to increment once per obs new value emition.
    obs.subscribe();
    obs.subscribe();
    obs.subscribe();

    subj.next(1);

    // Now this.counter === 3
  }
```

The result is that `this.counter` equals `3` after executing the above, it has been incremented one time per each subscription.

But how can we increment it once per `Observable`'s new value emission in a Reactive way?

I know that we should avoid state outside the Reactive flow, but still it is needed time to time in real world apps.

Comment: `observer.next(++counter);`

Comment: @Attersson: Could you update my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-update-global-state) to demonstrate it? I'm not very experienced with RxJS and not sure how to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you see number `3` is a little different. When you use `of(1)` it emits one `next` notification and right after that the `complete` notification. It does this every time you call `obs.subscribe()`.

So if you want to see `1` you need make an intermediate Subject where you make all subscriptions and then this intermediate Subject subscribe to the source Observable (with `publish()` operator most easily that creates the Subject for you):

```
const obs: ConnectableObservable<number> = of(1).pipe(
  tap((): void => {
    ++this.counter;
  }),
  publish(),
) as ConnectableObservable<number>;

obs.subscribe();
obs.subscribe();
obs.subscribe();

obs.connect();
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-update-global-state-ejdkie?file=app/app.component.ts

Be aware that `of(1)` will emit `complete` notification anyway which means that the subject inside `publish()` will complete as well. This might (or might not) be a problem for you but it really depends on your use-case.

**Edit**: This is updated demo where source is Subject: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-update-global-state-bws36m?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for my lack of knowledge in the area of RxJS and the confusion it caused. I used `of(1)` just a simplest (in my mind) example of some arbitrary `Observable`. However, thanks to your clarification, I see that it carries out some specific properties. I've updated my question and demo using a `Subject` and it still results in `this.counter` being equal to `3`. Please see if it makes a difference as to generalize my question.

Comment: If your source Observable is in fact Subject it's even easier with just `share()` operator. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-update-global-state-bws36m?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Awesome! So, depending on the source of the `Observable`, we have `share()` and `publish()` in our toolbox. I've played with them a little and ended up with the conclusion that I cannot distinct when one works and other does not and vice versa. Could you expand on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this please once. I cannot run it anywhere. If it gives an error let me know

```
  public counter: number = 0;
  public items: any = [];

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const obs: Observable<number> = of(1).pipe(
      tap((value): void => {
        if(! Array.prototype.includes(value)) {
           this.items.push(value);
            ++this.counter;
         }
      }));

    // this.counter increments for each subscription.
    // How to make it increment once per obs new value emission.
    obs.subscribe(1);
    obs.subscribe(2);
    obs.subscribe(1);

    // Now this.counter === 3
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This assumes `this.counter` supposed to keep a number of unique items emitted by the `Observable`. However, the question is generic in this regard meaning we should not make assumptions about the global state properties. I updated my question for more clarity on this.